# Unable to send an associative array in JSON format in Zend to client

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, associative-array, helper

In one of my actions in a controller, I'm using the json view helper to send back a response to an ajax request. On the client side I alert the data that is passed to the success callback function. It works fine as long as the response is a number or an array with default keys. Once I try to send an associative array, it alerts with [object Object].
Server code:

```
$childArray = array('key'=>'value');
$this->_helper->json($childArray);
```

javascript:

```
function displayChildren(data){
    alert(data);
}
...    
$.ajax({
        url: "/po/add", dataType: "json",
    data: {format: "json"}, success: displayChildren
});
```

I have no idea what am I doing wrong here, so any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. Associative arrays in Javascript are objects. Alert won't iterative over the object's properties and just outputs [object Object]. The key/value pairs you set on the PHP side are there and be accessed. try `alert(data.key)` and you should get `value`.

Comment: @anorflame use firebug console debug method its better then alert.

Comment: use console.log('anything, even an object') in firefox w/ firebug ;)